# wordpress custom type active menu in header

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

A have a page name Corporate, that shows me a custom type posts named documents with diferente categories in it. How can i make in the header corporate active when in front the active page is Corporate

Answer (score 0):

You can do in your header something like below

```
global $post;
$CurrentPageID = $post->ID;
if($CurrentPageID == 20){ // suppose 20 is Page ID of Corporate
     /* Here you can put code to make it active */
}
```